Hey guys i'm looking to obtain 1.05 Sepolia ETH for for my bot project
Hey guys i'm looking to obtain 1.05 Sepolia ETH for my bot project, if you can help out in funding my project with Sepolia ETH for my bot project I would be grateful for your help. thank you in advance: 0x8626f6940E2eb28930eFb4CeF49B2d1F2C9C1199
thank you your kindness

I've sent 1.05 Sepolia ETH: https://sepolia.etherscan.io/tx/0xf9a4ee72ca1208fa272292009f6d0db20f570233196d6a3f5709e9cbf52df5e4.
